# leap year mean in matlab

Tags: matlab, mean, leap-year

good morning. I have a matrix (eout) with 14610 rows and 16 column.
14610 row represent one of each day of the period between 01-01-1960 and 31-12-2000.

What I need is a new matrix with 40 rows and 16 columns with a mean for each year.
something like a mean of 365 rows continuously.
The problem I have are the leap years each 4 years.

Suggestions to solve this?

Comment: It shouldn't be hard with matlabs date functions to collect them accordingly.

Comment: You should be able to do it nice and neatly using `accumarray`. Can you post a small subset of your data so I can see how you are storing it?

Comment: I've already solved my problem so it won't be necessary to post my dataset.
Thanks for your concern! It was really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, to get the number of days for a given year:

```
function n = ndays(year)
    tmp = repmat([1,1,0,0,0],numel(year),1);
    n = datenum([year(:)+1,tmp])-datenum([year(:), tmp]);
end
```

With this, you could collect the rows e.g. with `mat2cell`:

```
rows_per_year = ndays(1960:2000);
chunks = mat2cell(yourInputMatrix, rows_per_year, size(yourInputMatrix,2));
means = cellfun(@(x) mean(x,1), chunks);
```

(The latter part comes untested..)